# How can I disallow restore from backup on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to disallow restore from backup. How can I do this? One Of my friends said to me

> "Take a certificate for your database and anyone cant restore from your backup"

I searched about certificate but I didn't find anything. I want to be sure that nobody copy my database from backup or the other ways.

Is there anyway about this problem?

Comment: Could you simply encrypt the backup file?

Comment: I serched for encrypting but can someone decrypt the databse?

Comment: A backup that can't be restored from doesn't sound like it would be much use...

Comment: Can you add more context? Do you want to make backup files secure? Or prevent actual RESTOREs on the original database servers

Comment: I am assuming that access to SQL Server is locked down, so your main concern is the backup files. You could use one of many available encryption tools to encrypt a backup file. You could then decrypt the backup file prior to a restore. Something like http://www.truecrypt.org/ comes to mind as a possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Quick answer: You can't.

Physical access to the backup file will allow someone to restore it. The password feature isn't secure and will be removed anyway. See "[Security Considerations for Backup and Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190964.aspx)" on MSDN

To prevent someone running RESTORE and destroying a working database, then ensure that only the correct folk have permissions to do this

Comment: Thank you for your Quick answer.. Are you sure isnt this possible? I dont want anbody copy my database.. I am not sql admin on sql server. So someone can copy my db. Isnt there any solution without SQL Encryption?

Comment: you can't stop someone copying it. they may be able to export it without admin or physical access